# Adding custom class objects to listbox in c#

Tags: c#, class, .net-2.0

i have a class which looks like this

```
public class Process_Items
{
    String Process_Name;
    int Process_ID;
    //String Process_Title;
    public string ProcessName
    {
        get { return Process_Name; }
        set { this.Process_Name = value; }
    }
    public int ProcessID
    {
        get { return Process_ID; }
        set { this.Process_ID = value; }
    }
}
```

now i want to create a Process_Items[] Array and display all the elements in a multi column listbox. Such that first column must have the processName and 2nd must have the processID. How can i achieve this in C# 2.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a ListView control and add two columns (ListBox only has one column)

```
Process_Items[] items = new Process_Items[] // Initialize array

foreach(Process_Items p in items) {
    listView.Items.Add(p.ProcessName).Subitems.Add(p.ProcessID.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A list box has a single ListItem (string) displayed to the user.

So you could override ToString() as

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} [ProcID: {1}]", this.Process_Name , this.ProcessID);
}
```

If this is for a winforms app, have a look at the ListView Control or a DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

What kind of control do you use for the list? If you use a ListView, then you can do like this (assuming that *instance* is a Process_Items - which btw is a strange name for a class IMO - instance):

```
listView1.Items.Add(instance.ProcessName).SubItems.Add(instance.ProcessID.ToString());
```