# Putting two-dimensional array in listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

So I have this array

```
string[,] cars = new String[2, 2] { 
                { "VW Golf GTI", "30000" }, 
                { "Porsche GT3", "300000" }, 
                { "Porsche Cayenne", "80000" }, 
                { "BMW M6", "90000" } 
            };
```

And want to put everything in a listbox, and I thought this would work, but it doesn't :/

```
lstBoxMarket.Items.AddRange(cars);
```

Now how do I put everything in the listbox in the format

Car - Price ?

Comment: Your code cannot be complied, zagged array should be use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794163/adding-custom-class-objects-to-listbox-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[,] cars = new string[4, 2] {
    { "VW Golf GTI", "30000" },
    { "Porsche GT3", "300000" },
    { "Porsche Cayenne", "80000" },
    { "BMW M6", "90000" }
};

for (int i = 0; i < cars.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    lstBoxMarket.Items.Add(cars[i, 0] + " - " + cars[i, 1]);
}
```

Your version of `cars` will not currently compile as you are specifying constants for the array initializers (2 rows by 2 columns) but your data has 4 rows.

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The better approach would be to Bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of a new class the data model Car type

Your view

**.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Your model
**Car.cs**

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your view model will have a Collection that will be bound to ItemsSource

**CarViewModel.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> DataCollection { get; set; }

DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Car> 
{ 
    new Car { Name = "VW Golf GTI", Id = 30000 }, 
    new Car { Name = "Porsche GT3", Id = 30000 }, 
    new Car { Name = "Porsche Cayenne", Id = 80000 }, 
    new Car { Name = "BMW M6", Id = 90000 }
};
```

Comment: +1 for a nice answer. However, a single `TextBlock` bound to your model via a converter (or using `StringFormat`) or single view model property might be better so that the end result isn't logically three separate text blocks. Three separate text blocks will be read as three separate strings by screen readers, for example.

Answer (score 1):

USE `DataSource` property to load data of multidimensional array.

```
listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
    listBox1.DataSource = cars;
```