# Filling a listbox with random items from array

Tags: c#, arrays, random, listbox

I've got two arrays; richcars & cars. I want to fill up lstBoxGarage with random items (4 from cars and 1 from richcars)
Now I have no idea how to do this, and I was hoping you guys could help me out.
At the moment I have this, but this fills the listbox with all the items obviously..

```
  for (int i = 0; i < richcars.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    lstBoxGarage.Items.Add(richcars[i, 0]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < cars.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    lstBoxGarage.Items.Add(cars[i, 0]);
  }
```

Could anyone help me with this random thing?

Here are my two arrays

```
          string[,] richcars = new string[10, 2] {
    { "Porsche Cayenne Turbo", "108000" },
    { "Porsche Panamera GTS", "111000"},
    { "Porsche 911 Carrera 4S", "105000"},
    { "Porsche Cayman S", "65000"},
    { "Porsche 911 Turbo", "140000"},
    { "Ferrari California", "190000"},
    { "BMW M3", "60000"},
    { "BMW M6", "105000"},
    { "Maserati GranTurismo S", "125000"},
    { "Audi R8 V10", "150000" }
};

      string[,] cars = new string[6, 2] {
    { "VW Golf GTI", "25000" },
    { "Mini Cooper S", "25000" },
    { "Jeep Wrangler", "25000" },
    { "Audi A4", "35000" },
    { "Nissan 370Z ", "35000" },
    { "Ford Focus ST", "25000" }
};
```

Comment: as others have pointed out in their answers to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880707/putting-two-dimensional-array-in-listbox), it would be better *not* to use a two-dimensional array but to define your own `Car` class instead.

Comment: Try by random a number in range from 0 to each array length - 1 and add to the list. To random you can use : `new Random().next(0, richcars.GetLength(0) -1))`. For the 4 cars from cars, check if it already contained the car by `lstBoxGarage.Contains(car-object);`

Comment: But *don't* create a new `Random` every time, this will not be random at all; re-use the same static `Random` for every call to `Next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Random class to generate random numbers

```
int limit = richcars.GetLength(0)
 for (int i = 0; i < limit ; i++)
 {
    Random random = new Random();

    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, limit);
    if (lstBoxGarage.FindStringExact(richcars[randomNumber, 0]) == -1)
       lstBoxGarage.Items.Add(richcars[randomNumber , 0]);
    else
        i--;
 }
```

Comment: this may add the same car multiple times; probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: I added a condition to prevent the duplicate.

Comment: Hmm this kinda works but it added one car 10 times and then one other car :/

Comment: Thanks but I still get 10 times the same car

Comment: I've added the two arrays in my first post

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Random random = new Random();
lstBoxGarage.Add(richcars[random.Next(0,richcars.GetLength(0)),0]);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var car = cars[random.Next(0,cars.GetLength(0)),0];
        if (lstBoxGarage.Contains(car))
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            lstBoxGarage.Add(car);
        }
    }
```

But notice that this only store the car name, to store with the price, you should create a Car class with name and price properties